# Embedding portlets in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, portlet

Is there any way I could embed a portlet inside a JSF application? I've been searching around and couldn't get anything on that regard, but instead with things like LifeRay or any other containers.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your portlet container? Websphere Portal? Apache Pluto?

Comment: I was looking at OpenPortlet-Container.

Answer (score 2):

A portlet needs to run in a portlet container. It's the same idea that a servlet doesn't just run on the JVM itself; it needs the support of an application server to help manage it.

So to just drop a portlet into a JSF application doesn't make sense unless you're application server can double as a portlet container.

Comment: Alternatively, is there any way I could embed a JSF application without using an iFrame on an application?
We are looking for a kind of portal site that let us redirect to different applications and offer others directly embedded on it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Also, you need to be sure that your application server supports JSF Bridge. By the way, you don't embed a portlet in a JSF application, you embed JSF code in a portlet.

Comment: You can use JSF in portlets. I haven't done this myself but I'm sure some googling should be able to find you a tutorial or two.

For integrating, I know that WebSphere Portal can use the WebSphere Application Integrator to help create a unified look and feel across external sites. Other platforms may provide similar tools but I;ve only worked with WebSphere Portal.